# Add custom method to ref in react

Tags: reactjs

I have attached a ref to a html component like this:

```
const myRef = useRef(null);

<button ref={myRef} />
```

I want to customize `myRef`, I want to add a util method called `myRef.customMethod`.

Is it possible to run a function everytime `myRef` gets set?

Comment: You could use a callback function for setting the ref `<button ref={(ref) => {/*access or save ref */}}/>`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs for more info.

Comment: Oh wow thank you at @NickG I thought this way was deprecated. But now I can't see any notes on its deprecation. Is it safe to assume this is future safe?

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty sure this is future safe, as this is afaik currently the only supported way to manage refs completely by yourself (and not let React handle them for you).

Comment: Thanks very much! If you can post that as solution I would love to accept it @NickG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a callback function for setting the ref:

```
<button ref={(ref) => {/*access or save ref */}}/>
```

See [React Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) for more info.

As this is currently the only way to manage refs by yourself (and not let React handle them for you), i'm pretty sure this is future safe.